# How to reset the id of the orders generated by Commerce module

Tags: commerce

I just finish a website which include a cart. I'm using the [commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

In the development stage I've been making some test. Now I just deleted all these testing order, but now the id of the next order is something like 189. I need to put this number to 1.

**Which database table do I need to truncate to get it done?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commerce order module defines two tables, `commerce_order` and `commerce_order_revision`; you should truncate both of those to clear the data and reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` counter.

In MySQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE commerce_order
TRUNCATE TABLE commerce_order_revision
```

Or using the API:

```
db_truncate('commerce_order');
db_truncate('commerce_order_revision');
```

Comment: Note that you must only do this after manually deleting all orders through Drupal's user interface. Otherwise you will be left with stale field values, line items and so on which will result in Exceptions when you attempt to save a new order with an id that has left over data.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional thoughts regarding resetting the entire "order" environment back to the first order...

In addition to truncating the `commerce_order` and `commerce_order_revision` tables after manually deleting through the admin interface as indicated above you should should determine if the following tables exist and need to be deleted (if you are using the contributed modules).

`commerce_invoice` - if using Invoice module

`commerce_paypal_ipn` - if using PayPal modules

`commerce_payment_transaction` - if using PayPal modules

`commerce_payment_transaction_revision` - if using PayPal modules

I ran into issues when these tables where not reset/truncated.